# Inputting Scanner Barcodes in an excel column in random orders, tally occurrences, Add tally to its running total in correct cell

Tags: excel, vba

1. I scan barcodes all day in random orders
2. My scanner Dumps barcodes into Excel (Column B) at end of day
3. I want VBA to count how many times each different individual barcode was
   scanned
4. Then take those tallies to each barcodes (each one is referenced in a cell in Column F)
   and add them to their running totals in the correct cell (each has its own cell in Column H)

This isnt working and I'm not sure why...

```
Private Sub addButton_Click()

    Dim Barcode As Variant
    Dim Scanner As Variant
    Dim Inventory As Variant

    Scanner = Range("B3,B36").Value
    Inventory = Range("G3, G61").Value



    i = 3
    For Each Barcode In Scanner
        If Barcode.Value = Inventory.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
            Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 9) + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Barcode
    i = i + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is the `i = i + 1` outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Match to check your inventory for each barcode:

```vb
Private Sub addButton_Click()

    Dim Barcode As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Scans As Range, m
    Dim Inventory As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet               'or some specific sheet
    Set Scans = ws.Range("B3:B36")     'values from scanner
    Set Inventory = ws.Range("G3:G61") 'description has Col F?  Edited
    
    For Each Barcode In Scans.Cells
        'find the barcode in the inventory list
        m = Application.Match(Barcode.Value, Inventory, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a match: increment value in ColH
            With Inventory.Cells(m).EntireRow.Columns("H")
                .Value = .Value + 1
            End With
        Else
            'no match: what to do?
        End If
    Next Barcode

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried running this and am getting a 438 run-time error @ .Value = .Value + 1 line. Is this shorthand and something I should know to put in front of the period?

Comment: Sorry made a typo in setting the Inventory range

Comment: Ha I actually caught that typo before and it wasn’t working but it was due to something on my end. This worked perfectly thank you